# Trying to connect to my Atlas cluster with node.js driver but get "TypeError: client.close is not a function" instead

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm a newbie on stackoverflow. I'm beginning with mongodb and node.js, following step-by-step tutorials from W3S. I succeeded in connecting to my cluster with mongosh client and performed basic CRUD operations and queries. So far, so good. My problem started when I tried to connect to my cluster from node.js. I just copy-pasted the sample code from W3S and then replaced the uri variable default string with my cluster uri. When running my node.js app, I get a "TypeError: client.close is not a function".

I'm using the last version to date of node and mongo driver.

I've tried to find an answer on stackoverflow and other community forums, but nothing that fixed my issue. I tried to connect again and again using code snippets from other tutorials, including the full driver example code provided by Atlas. I've checked my uri string over and over but did not find anything suspect. At some point, I thought the problem might come from my password encoding, so I tried the code below from MongoDB troubleshouting page. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything. What did I miss ? Any help would be greatly appreciated !

`

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const username = encodeURIComponent("<myusername>");
const password = encodeURIComponent("<mypassword>");
const cluster = "cluster0.2lulwez.mongodb.net";


let uri =
  `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@${cluster}/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();


  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably is the user, the password or the url that is wrong or your ip address is not well configured in the atlas for the connection well.
I proved and works, you can add try catch to see the error:

Replace your function run, with this:

```
async function run() {
  try {
    console.log("connecting...");
    await client.connect();
    console.log("connected...");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    try {
      console.log("closing...");
      await client.close();
      console.log("closed ...");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Source:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @techdobycon. In the meantime, I realized that a handful of nodejs apps that I wrote previously were not working anymore. Bottom line: I uninstalled and reinstalled node and npm manually, which is quite painful on Mac OSX, btw. Everything has been working fine since then. thanks again !